# Oracle SQL query with Left Joins and concatenated values taking too much time to run

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, subquery, left-join

I have joined 3 subqueries to obtain a final result. However, the issue is that it is taking 45 minutes to return the result.

I need help in optimizing the time taken to run the query and return the result.

Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    C.TRANSACTION_ID, 
    A.LOAN_NUMBER, A.TRAN_DATE, A.ADVANCE_TYPE, A.ADV_PROCESSOR_ID, 
    A.ADV_TRAN_CODE, A.CORP_PAYEE_ID, A.REASON_CODE, 
    A.CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION, A.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT, 
    C.CLAIM_AMOUNT, A.PAYEE_ID, 
    B.DEPT, B.CAT, B.DESCRIPTION AS SUBCAT, B.LIITEM_NOTE, 
    B.COMPL_DT, B.SVC_FROM_DT, B.SVC_TO_DT, 
    NVL(B.VENDOR_NAME,A.PAYEE_ID) AS VENDOR_NAME, B.INVOICE_NUMBER, 
    C.CLAIM_ID, C.CLAIM_STATUS, C.CLAIM_TYPE, C.LOSS_REASON, C.DETAILED_LOSS_REASON
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         LOAN_NUMBER, 
         NVL(CA_HIST_ORIGINAL_DISB_DATE,CA_HIST_TRANSACTION_DATE) TRAN_DATE, 
         CASE   
             WHEN CA_HIST_RECOVERABLE_CODE IN ('T') THEN 'TPCA'     
             WHEN CA_HIST_RECOVERABLE_CODE IN ('N') THEN 'NRCA'     
             WHEN CA_HIST_RECOVERABLE_CODE IN ('R') THEN 'MRCA'  
         END AS ADVANCE_TYPE, 
         CA_HIST_PROCESSOR_ID AS ADV_PROCESSOR_ID, 
         CA_HIST_TRANSACTION_CODE ADV_TRAN_CODE, 
         CA_HIST_CORPORATE_PAYEE_ID CORP_PAYEE_ID, 
         CA_HIST_REASON_CODE REASON_CODE, 
         CA_HIST_REASON_DESCRIPTION AS CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION, 
         (SELECT PAYEE_ADDRESS_LINE_1 
          FROM CPI.D_PAYEE@OCN_DBL_MICCRPT_CONN 
          WHERE PAYEE_ID = CA_HIST_PAYEE_ID AND ROWNUM = 1) AS PAYEE_ID, 
         (CASE 
              WHEN CA_HIST_TRANSACTION_CODE IN (710, 711, 712, 713, 714, 766) 
                  THEN (CA_HIST_ADVANCE_AMOUNT) * - 1 
              ELSE (CA_HIST_ADVANCE_AMOUNT) 
          END) TRANSACTION_AMOUNT,  
         (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NVL(CA_HIST_ORIGINAL_DISB_DATE, CA_HIST_TRANSACTION_DATE), CA_HIST_CORPORATE_PAYEE_ID, CA_HIST_REASON_CODE, (CASE WHEN CA_HIST_TRANSACTION_CODE IN (710,711,712,713,714,766) THEN ABS(CA_HIST_ADVANCE_AMOUNT) * - 1   ELSE (CA_HIST_ADVANCE_AMOUNT) END) ORDER BY NVL(CA_HIST_ORIGINAL_DISB_DATE,CA_HIST_TRANSACTION_DATE))) ROW_CORP FROM BDE.CORPORATE_ADV_HIST@OCN_MICC_GC_RPT_CDW_CONN) A
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TRUNC(PYMT.CREATD_DT), PYMT.TRANS_CD, PYMT.CORP_ADV_CD, PYMT.RSN_CD, PYMT.DISBD_AMT 
                             ORDER BY TRUNC(PYMT.CREATD_DT))) AS ROW_LPS, 
         LITEM.SVCR_LOAN_NUM AS LOAN_NUMBER, 
         TRUNC(PYMT.CREATD_DT) AS TRANDATE, 
         PYMT.TRANS_CD, PYMT.CORP_ADV_CD, PYMT.RSN_CD, 
         INV.DEPT, LITEM.CAT, LITEM.SUB_CAT AS DESCRIPTION, 
         LITEM.LIITEM_NOTE, PYMT.DISBD_AMT AS AMOUNT, 
         LITEM.LI_ITEM_DT AS COMPL_DT, LITEM.SVC_FROM_DT, 
         LITEM.SVC_TO_DT, INV.VEND_NM AS VENDOR_NAME, 
         LITEM.INVC_NUM AS INVOICE_NUMBER 
     FROM 
         LS_INVC.INVC@OCN_MICC_GC_RPT_cdw_CONN INV, 
         LS_INVC.INVC_LIITEM@OCN_MICC_GC_RPT_cdw_CONN LITEM, 
         LS_INVC.INVC_LIITEM_PAYMT@OCN_MICC_GC_RPT_cdw_CONN PYMT 
     WHERE
         INV.INVC_ID = LITEM.INVC_ID 
         AND LITEM.INVC_LIITEM_ID = PYMT.INVC_LIITEM_ID) B ON TO_NUMBER(A.LOAN_NUMBER) = B.LOAN_NUMBER AND A.TRAN_DATE=B.TRANDATE AND A.CORP_PAYEE_ID||'_'||A.REASON_CODE=B.CORP_ADV_CD||'_'||B.RSN_CD AND A.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT=B.AMOUNT AND A.ROW_CORP=B.ROW_LPS
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.TRANSACTION_DATE, SUBSTR(C.CATEGORY_CODE, 1, 10), (C.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT) 
                            ORDER BY C.TRANSACTION_DATE) ROW_MICC, 
         TRANSACTION_ID, CATEGORY_CODE, TRANSACTION_AMOUNT, LOAN_NUM, 
         CLAIM_ID, TRANSACTION_DATE, CLAIM_AMOUNT, CLAIM_STATUS, 
         CLAIM_TYPE, LOSS_REASON, DETAILED_LOSS_REASON 
     FROM 
         MICC_RPT.CL_TRAN_LVL_DATA C) C ON B.LOAN_NUMBER = TO_NUMBER(C.LOAN_NUM) 
                                        AND B.TRANDATE = C.TRANSACTION_DATE 
                                        AND B.CORP_ADV_CD||'_'||B.RSN_CD = SUBSTR(C.CATEGORY_CODE, 1, 10) 
                                        AND B.AMOUNT = C.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT 
                                        AND B.ROW_LPS = C.ROW_MICC
WHERE 
    A.LOAN_NUMBER = '1234567890'
ORDER BY 
    A.LOAN_NUMBER, A.TRAN_DATE, A.ADV_TRAN_CODE, A.CORP_PAYEE_ID, 
    A.REASON_CODE, A.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT;
```

I only have read access to the database and cannot create indexes or alter the tables. I can only run the queries using select statements.

I have spent hours and hours searching a resolution online but am unable to find. Referring this issue to the stack overflow experts for resolution!

Comment: Unfortunately without both the execution plan and either rowcounts per plan line (SQL Monitor data) or time per plan line (ASH data), folks outside your organization who don't know your data cannot help with tuning SQL like this.

Comment: That being said, I can offer a few things to look at. First, you want a single loan number. So you want nested loops joins and index access to virtually everything. Ensure LOAN_NUMBER on BDE.CORPORATE_ADV_HIST@OCN_MICC_GC_RPT_CDW_CONN is indexed, remove the TO_NUMBER in `TO_NUMBER(A.LOAN_NUMBER)` so Oracle can apply your literal predicate to both query blocks, don't use functions like || in joins unless you create function-based indexes to support them, and ensure every join in here is on columns appropriately indexed. Query LOAN_NUMBER as a number, not a string.

Comment: Lastly, you are mainly pulling from the same remote database. Ensure that it is the driving site (you see REMOTE at the top of the execution plan) or at least that most of your subqueries have been shipped over to the rmote so you don't have nested loops over database links if you can avoid it.

Comment: Several of the tables are on a remote database, which can be challenging for the optimiser. Is there a way you can restructure it such that all the remote joins are done in one subquery or WITH clause and get the optimiser to execute that separately on the remote side using a [driving_site](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Comments.html#GUID-DDABFD2E-FE80-4A2D-99D2-87E61EFA2182) hint.